# Does there exists a "maximal" convergent series?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

My question is as follows: Does there exist a sequence $(a_n)$ of non-negative real numbers such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n < \infty$, but for any sequence $(b_n)$ of non-negative numbers with $b_n \to \infty$, we have $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nb_n = \infty$?

To me this seems to be asking if there is in some sense a "maximal" convergent series, as any "bigger" series diverges, where "bigger" means pointwise multiplied by some unbounded non-negative sequence. Thus my first thought to solve this was Zorn's lemma. I tried to define an order $\preceq$ on the space of all convergent non-negative sequences by saying $(x_n) \preceq (y_n)$ if there exists an unbounded sequence $(b_n)$ of non-negative numbers such that $y_n = b_nx_n$ for all $n$. But this order is not reflexive so we cannot use Zorn's lemma.

I did manage to prove a weaker version, namely that if $(b_n)$ is any unbounded non-negative sequence then we can find a non-negative sequence $(a_n)$ with $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n < \infty$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nb_n = \infty$, and I can easily extend it to finitely many $(b_n)$, but have not been able to extend it to infinitely many (i.e. for all unbounded sequences).

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that $\exists \{c_n\}$ monotonically increasing to $\infty$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_nc_n$ coverges.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/884782/prove-that-exists-c-n-monotonically-increasing-to-infty-such-that-su) (Also [(1)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/236511), [(2)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2896011)... frequently asked here)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a strictly increasing sequence of natural numbers $N_m$ such that $N_0 = 1$ and $\sum_{n=N_m}^\infty a_n \le 2^{-m} \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n $.  Define $b_n = m$ for $N_m \le n < N_{m+1}$.  Then
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n b_n = \sum_{m=0}^\infty \sum_{n = N_m}^\infty a_n\le 2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n < \infty $$

Comment: A variation on this theme is to take $N_m$ such that $\sum_{n=N_m}^{\infty}\,a_n<4^{-n} $ and let $b_n=2^m$ for $N_m\le n<N_{m+1}.$